# Where is the setting for sending email to a system user with ssmtp?

Tags: email, ssmtp

I'm using `ssmtp` for sending email (the setting is below)

Now when i run a `cron` command or an `at` command, mail is sent to

```
michel@mypi
```

which is `username @ machinename`

Now ofcourse this is not a valid email address, so i get errors in my gmail saying: `can't send email to michel@mypi`

How and where should i say that email to the user 'michel' should go to a particular email address?

The setting for ssmtp:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000 # Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=MYNAME@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=MyPi

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address 
# NO - Use the system generated From: address 
#FromLineOverride=YES 
AuthUser=MYNAME
AuthPass=MYPASS
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
```

Comment: How does gmail fit into this description?

Comment: ehm, i'm using the gmail account to send email with ssmtp

Comment: Ah, the error in my gmail is because I configured ssmtp to send email via gmail (see the config in the question) and for some reason the engine which sends email on behalf of `cron` uses that setting too, and so when `cron` sends email to `michel@mypi` it is sent back to my gmail account saying it can not send email to `michel@mypi`

Comment: @Michel ssmtp doesn't do local mail. If you want local mail and smart host sending, you will want a real MTA such as exim4 or postfix, which can do both.

Comment: @jordanm Yeah, i just noticed 1 minute ago that the MyPi were the mail goes to wasn't the machine name, but the `hostname` setting from the ssmtp config (which had the same value as my machine name). What ssmtp seems to do is to add the setting in the hostname to the local user name and use that as an email address. I tried exim4 once and i couldn't get it to work, and I'm afraid to reset my mail install just for this issue. Is there a way to workaround this? Say let `ssmtp` ignore local mail, or don't let `cron` and `at` send email?

Comment: @Michel You can set MAILTO="foo@gmail.com" in your crontab file so that the email goes to an internet accessible address.

Comment: Does that also work for the `at` command?

Comment: Oh, i just tried: it doesn't get picked up by the `at` command, is there a way?

Comment: @jordanm: the MAILTO does work for the cron, great!

Comment: ssmtp does NOT verify the SSL/TLS certificate of the remote server on the current debian, ubuntu and redhat releases and also does NOT verify the hostname of the certificate. This is a major issue, as this effectively renders the encryption useless and your password is being transmitted alike to being plaintext and anyone can sniff it. ssmtp has had no active development since atleast 2009. So, if you care about the security of the email account you use for your servers outgoing emails, do NOT use ssmtp, but postfix (or something else) instead: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118101/72087

Comment: Check out this one for the simplest answer:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line

Answer (score 12):

Sorry to raise the dead, but I stumbled across this via Google and have just solved it: the /etc/ssmtp/revaliases is only the aliases for the FROM: addresses.

Aliases for TO: addresses would normally need to be set in /etc/aliases, but SSMTP doesn't read this! Instead, you need to edit /etc/mail.rc and add a line such as

```
alias root root<yourname@youremail.com>
```

See http://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=591 for more info.

UPDATE 2019-05-07 - According to comments below, the later versions of the package that are now in EPEL (if you're on RedHat family distros) now **do** read the `/etc/aliases` file, so check your version!

Comment: No need to apologise - it's great that you post a solution, it will help anyone else who tries to use this and runs into the same problem!

Comment: This was it! I think most of the other guides that mention revaliases work because the uid being sent to is <1000 and the root address just collects all of them.

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: Just a note that ssmtp version 2.64 which is in the EPEL repo for CentOS 7 does in fact use /etc/aliases instead of /etc/mail.rc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the file /etc/ssmtp/revaliases to enter your aliases, e.g.

```
michel:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. When i send mail to michel it does not work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What do the logs say?

Comment: I get the same error in my mail. What i described earlier (What ssmtp seems to do is to add the setting in the hostname to the local user name and use that as an email address.) still happens, the `revaliases` file isn't used. Isn't it btw strange that I have to specify a email server for an alias?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Simplest way to send one-line mail out via command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail)

Excerpt:

```
root=rpi3abc@gmail
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=rpi3abc@gmail.com
AuthPass=testing123
UseTLS=YES
```