# How to install postfix for sending mails to admin only?

Tags: email, configuration, postfix

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 13.10 on Digital Ocean.

I'd like to install `postfix` on the server, but I want it to be able to send e-mails only to my e-mail address whenever a system message wants to be sent to root.

Now I have my `postfix` installed as `local only`. This sends the messages to `/var/mail/root`.

Instead, I'd like my messages to go to my real e-mail (`example@gmail.com`), but I don't want to allow other users/sites to send e-mail (like for example from PHP's `mail()`).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this

### Using SSMTP:

You can find a detailed article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/51819/how-to-setup-email-alerts-on-linux-using-gmail/). (Please consider *Zulakis*' comment below regarding security: I let *ssmtp* solution here for your knowledge, but prefer *postfix* solution)

Install ssmtp

```
sudo aptitude install ssmtp
```

Edit the configuration file:

```
sudo vim /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

And configure it with your gmail account:

```
root=username@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
hostname=username@gmail.com
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=yes
```

### Using Postfix

If you want to use your postfix install, you can configure it to work with your gmail account. You can find a detailed article [here](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/).

Check that you have all the needed dependencies

```
mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

Edit the configuration of postfix:

```
sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

And configure it with your gmail account:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Create the file with your password:

```
vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

And add the following lines

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    USERNAME@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

### Allowing root only

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with

> I don't want to allow other users/sites to send e-mail (like for example from PHP's mail())

But for blocking mail access per user or per domain, you can edit the following file:

```
vim /etc/mail/access
```

And add rules such as:

```
To:a1@server.vikas.com        REJECT            # Reject a1 user from recieving mails
From:a1@server.vikas.com     REJECT           # Reject a1 user from sending mails
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: For everyone reading this answer: ssmtp does NOT verify the SSL/TLS certificate of the remote server on the current debian, ubuntu and redhat releases and also does NOT verify the hostname of the certificate. This is a major issue, as this effectively renders the encryption useless and your password is being transmitted alike to being plaintext and anyone can sniff it. 

ssmtp has had no active development since atleast 2009.

So, if you care about the security of the email account you use for your servers outgoing emails, do NOT use ssmtp, but use the postfix solution proposed here!

Comment: There seems there is some activity here: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ssmtp/commits/master. So while it may not be an active development, the package doesn't look abandoned either.

Comment: Just to add here - I see now last work Oct '22 so still not abandonned.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias entry in your alias_maps file like

```
root:       example@gmail.com
```

This will send all mails of `root` to `example@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are asking for  is only partly possible, since the two requirements (*accepting (and forwarding) administrative emails* and *rejecting mails from other users*) are not orthogonal.

e.g. what happens, if a service wants to send an email to `root` via PHP's `mail()` interface? should it be allowed? forbidden? what happens (as is usually the case) if a service runs as an unprivileged user instead of `root`?

so i guess, what you really want is to only use the MTA for sending administrative emails from your local machine.

this can be accomplished by configuring your MTA to do the following (these are generic instructions to configure any MTA, not specific to `postfix`):

- only accept emails from localhost (thus it will not accept emails from *outside*); do this by configuring your MTA to listen on `127.0.0.1` and/or by setting up a firewall that blocks all *incoming* traffic on port `25`.
- only accept emails for administrative accounts (`root`, `webmaster`, `postmaster`, `abuse`,...) and setup an alias to forward these emails to `me@example.com`

given that you control your own server, there is little use in blocking certain applications (e.g. `php`) from sending emails via your own mail-server. simply configure these applications to use a different mailserver (if need be), or re-evaluate your requirement.